# Strcat not appending a character

Tags: c++, char, strcat

```
char* oledScreen::getCurrentTime(){
   char* hour = malloc(16);
   snprintf(hour, 16, "%d", getHour());

   char* minute = malloc(16);
   snprintf(minute, 16, "%d", getMinute());

   char* firstPart = strcat(getHour() < 10 ? strcat("0",hour) : hour, ":");
   const char* secondPart = getMinute() < 10 ? strcat("0",minute) : minute;

   return strcat(firstPart, secondPart);
};
```

I'm trying to append two integers, which I can obtain using `getHour()` and `getMinute()`. However, I need to check if one of these two are less than 10: if so, I need to append a 0 so that the output is such that: `0X`, where `X` is `getHour()` or `getMinute()`.

My problem is that it does not append the `:` character. For instance, if `getHour() = 9` and `getMinute() = 15`. The output of `getCurrentTime()` is `0915` and not `09:15`. Do you have any idea why this is like this?

Comment: You also have memory leaks, who will `free` the memory allocated for `hour` and `minute`?

Comment: `snprintf(buffer, buffer_size, "%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute())`

Comment: By the way, your code isn't C, it's C++. So you should not be using `char` arrays or `snprintf` to begin with.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude or malloc...

Comment: `strcat("0",hour)` adds whatever is in `hour` to the string literal `"0"`. You cannot add something to a string literal. should give you a warning: https://godbolt.org/z/a48x3bnYo

Comment: @Armin Montigny Please pay careful attention to the whole source code before deciding to edit language tags, _especially_ when answers are posted in one language - after which it is too late to change tags . See the C and C++ tag wikis for tag usage guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, `strcat("0",hour)` will lead to *undefined behavior* as you attempt to modify the literal string `"0"` which isn't allowed.

Instead of using multiple `strcat` calls, why not simply create a string large enough to fit the result, and use `snprintf` to put contents into the string?

Using `snprintf` will also make it easier to optionally add a zero-prefix to the hour value.

Perhaps something like this:

```
// Allocate memory, and actually create the string
// 2 for hour, 2 for minutes, 1 for colon, 1 for terminator
char *result = malloc(6);

snprintf(result, 6, "%02d:%02d", getHour(), getMinute());

return result;
```

As mentioned in comments, a better solution would be to pass in the `result` array as an argument to the function. The would handle ownership of the `result` array better, and might not even need dynamic allocation.

<sub>[Note that the above is a pure C solution, it's not even valid in C++. I wrote it before noticing that the code in the question is really C++.]</sub>

---

Considering that you really seem to be programming in C++, not C, then a solution using string streams and `std::string` would be more appropriate:

```
std::string oledScreen::getCurrentTime(){
    std::ostringstream oss;

    oss << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << getHour() << ':'
        << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << getMinute();

    return oss.str();
}
```

Comment: Having the caller pass in a buffer (and size) is probably even better, because I guess mostly a stack-based buffer can be used by the caller, avoiding heap allocation.

Comment: In addition, using `malloc`/`free` in C++ is highly problematic and not recommended, since default constructors/destructors won't get called.